# How to fetch data only on first click via react-query and then disable refetch on subsequent clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-query

I encountered a problem while implementing the form where the **data** used in select, retrieved from the database via react-query, **should only be retrieved once when clicking on input, and subsequent clicks should not cause a refetch**.

***How to do it in clean way?***

Hook:

```
export const useUnitOfMeasureSelectData = ({
  queryPageIndex,
  queryPageSize,
  queryFilters,
  enabled,
  refetchOnWindowFocus,
}) => {
  return useQuery(
    ["unitofmeasure-list", queryPageIndex, queryPageSize, queryFilters],
    () => fetchItemData(queryPageIndex, queryPageSize, queryFilters),
    {
      keepPreviousData: true,
      staleTime: 60000,
      enabled,
      refetchOnWindowFocus,
      select: (data) => {
        const categories = data.data.results.map((obj) => ({
          value: obj.id,
          label: obj.name,
        }));
        return categories;
      },
    }
  );
};
```

In component calling `onClick={()=>refetch()}` refetch data on every click.

```
  const {
    data: unitOfMeasureSelectData = [],
    refetch: refetchUnitOfMeasureSelectData,
  } = useUnitOfMeasureSelectData({
    queryPageIndex: queryPageIndex,
    queryPageSize: queryPageSize,
    queryFilters: filterString,
    enabled: false,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });
```

Comment: You could possibly `const selectFetched = useRef(false)` and after the first fetch update to `selectFetched.current = false;` - and then do a check for each subsequent click on the select?

Comment: @JohnDetlefs It could work, but the form contains several elements desiring the behavior described in the question. I think I will do just the way you describe. I'm chasing a deadline, and that seems like a fine solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like you want a lazy query with infinite stale time:

```
const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)

useQuery(key, fn, { enabled, staleTime: Infinity })
```

then, when you click on the input, you call `setEnabled: true`. The infinite stale time makes sure that the query is always considered fresh, so no more background refetch is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The button in react/native has a property `disabled` that you can set to false when you are done. Probably the way to do this is with `state`

```
<button disabled={this.state.btnDisable}/>
```

Then you can update the state when you first click the button

```
//class component
this.setState({btnDisable: false})

//function component
setbtnDisable(false)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure disabled property makes input or button non-clickable.

Comment: yes you are right, I was imagining a refresh button and submission button separately my apologies